# Empty FrameLayout Blocks Button Behind

Tags: android, button, imagebutton, android-framelayout

[image]

as you can see the backButton is behind the frame layout.

but i want to make this button clickable unless its visible.

im using scrollview, which means i cannot place BackButton Above.
because it will colapse when i scroll it up.

Heres the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop">

    </ImageView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.74"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


    //SOME CONTENT HERE, REMOVED FOR READABILITY


            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Simple question. How?

Comment: The simplest method would be to place the `FrameLayout` containing your `Button` *after* your `ScrollView`.

Comment: The frame layout should wrap content it is having!

Comment: Post your XML file as well

Comment: @KulsDroid added XML as you said

Comment: @Xenolion i'm sorry forgot to mention that this is scrollView

Comment: Place it after the `ScrollView` but before the closing `FrameLayout` tag - it'll be drawn on top of the `ScrollView`. There are better methods for achieving this layout overall anyway, with `CollpasingToolbarLayout` from the Android Design Support Library.

Comment: @PPartisan it should not be under the scrollview cause it shoudnt be scrolled together. it looks like this [scrollview[LinearLayout[framelayout[content]]]]

Comment: Why would it be scrolled together if it isn't inside the `ScrollView`? Your parent layout is a `FrameLayout`, so its children aren't positioned in relation to each other. Construct your layout as [parent_FrameLayout[ImageView][ScrollView][*your_button*]] and it will work, as the button will be drawn *over* the `ScrollView`

Comment: @PPartisan oh sorry, i missunderstood. how ever still cant do that because the button shouldnt be above the scrollview. when its scrolled up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be that neither you have only a single child inside your `FrameLayout` nor do you use the `android:layout_gravity" attribute. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

Comment: what about using RelativeLayout instead of FrameLayout? it still wont work

Comment: Yes this would be an option. You can also make (each of) your `FrameLayout's have one child only by wrapping the insides in another layout, for example a 'RelativeLayout'.

Comment: What else did you do?

Answer (score 0):

From the image you have uploaded I can see that the whole layout can be easily implemented using new Support Libraries in Android.

And if that is your case the whole Layout can be converted changed to use a `CoordinatorLayout` instead of using the `FrameLayout` directly. Check the following **image**. If that is what you want then follow along and if it is not exactly what you want you can **IGNORE** this Answer:

[image: CoordinatorLayout]

If you want something like this then `FrameLayout` might be a hard way to go while there exist support design libraries that will make your job easier.

In this case its `CoordinatorLayout` and `Collapsing Tool Bar` but even if you do not  want the Collapsing toolbar still Coordinator Layout is the best Alternative for this!

If you want to know more about support design Libraries then here is a post [Android Developers Google Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).
Coordinator Layout it is easily to make layout of the nature like yours and its a smart alternative, For the image I have uploaded the code will be something like this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.sample.foo.usingcoordinatorlayout.FabAndSnackbarActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:title="@string/collapsing_toolbar">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/bg"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="@string/long_latin"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/mascot_icon"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For Learning more about all this Support Library and more other interesting features, check [this link its a good blog post](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/) about all these! Always remember you will always add support design in your app.gradle file just like appcompat. But the description from those links will consist all these information. Happy Coding!

Answer (score -2):

Make your covering framework dont custom  the touch event to let your underneath button be able to handle the touch event. So it is clickable.